# Is there a good alternative for a continuous form in Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have two tables, tblMachines and tblSchedule.  I want to query out of tblMachines a list of Machines which have their scheduling bit set.  I want to display this list of machines on a "continuous form" with 24 unbound text boxes after each Machine, one for each hour of the day.  From there I want to query tblSchedule and change the background color of the unbound textboxes appropriately for each machine and scheduling engagement.

With a continuous form

```
           1am 2am 3am 4am 5am 6am...
Machine1   [ ] [X] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]...
Machine2   [ ] [X] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]...
Machine3   [ ] [X] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]...
```

What I want.

```
           1am 2am 3am 4am 5am 6am...
Machine1   [ ] [X] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]...
Machine2   [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]...
Machine3   [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]...
```

My problem is obvious since I am using a continuous form.  I understand that.  Is there a better way to create a dynamic timetable/matrix on a form in Access?  I've tried a looped CreateControl in Form_Open but it complains about the state of the form which is undesirable.  Is it possible to create a spreadsheet and link each row to an individual record from my tblMachine query?

[edit]

tblMachine = [idx], [machine_name], [scheduling_bit (true/false)]

tblSchedule = [idx], [operation.idx], [machine.idx], [employee.idx], [scantype (0-start/1-stop)], [time]

Records in tblSchedule are created via barcode reader at each Machine.  Barcodes are scanned when an operation is started and stopped.

Comment: You won't be able to do it with unbound text boxes due to the problems you've already found.  You could possibly use a cross-tab query, but you'll have problems with the colouring - you'll have to use conditional formatting and that will only allow three or four colours.  What's the design of your two tables?

Comment: That makes little sense. Build a query based on the 2 tables that will display what you want, or buid the continuous form linked to the tblMachines and have your hourly boxes bound to a formula (`dFirst` or similar) that looksup into the tblSchedule. But the latter solution will be slow.

Comment: @Darren  tblMachine is just a list of machines with a scheduling bit [true/false].  tblSchedule contains [idx], [machineIDX], [employeeIDX], [scantype (0=start 1=stop)], [timeofEvent].  Each record in tblSchedule is created at the machine via barcode reader when an operation is started or stopped.  I just want a graphical view of when start and stop events happened for each machine.  Populating it I can handle, I just don't know how to create the grid/matrix.